# How to re-trigger productsRequest() from SKProductsRequestDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

My app got rejected twice because the IAP prices don't show up for the app reviewer. I'm quite stuck on this as it works fine on my iPhone.

My four subscriptions are retrieved and displayed in a tableview:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return options?.count ?? 0
    }

...

var options: [Subscription]?

extension SubscriptionService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        options = response.products.map { Subscription(product: $0) }
    }

    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        if request is SKProductsRequest {
            print("Subscription Options Failed Loading: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

The options are loaded automatically via `productsRequest` by the delegate `SKProductsRequestDelegate`.  I don't understand what I could have missed. Unless the reviewers are testing the app in offline mode and have no internet access? Could that be the case for security reasons?

Am I not supposed to load the products `productsRequest()` from the appstore and have the prices instead hardcoded on the client side?

**UPDATE:**
I can now replicate the issue:

If the device is in the Airplane mode and then I start the app, this method gets called naturally:

```
func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
```

But even after coming out of the airplane mode, there is no way that this function 
`productsRequest()` is re-raised.  Is there any way I could manually trigger than when the app comes back to foreground?

Comment: The first thing I can see is that you don't reload your table view after the products are loaded. Each time you enter your "store" view controller you can retry the product request if `options` is `nil`

Comment: To trigger when the app is foregrounded, implement an appdelegate method. There you might want to call a method that contains the code you are using to start the request